# In app purchase windows phone 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, crash, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, in-app-purchase

I have simple issue in my windows phone 8.1 RT app. I have implemented in app purchase in my app. It works normally, If I do in app purchase while BackgroundAudioPlayer is running, then after opening store CONFIRM PURCHASE page app crashes after 5-6 seconds sometimes after 10 secs.

**Note:** I am able to reproduce this issue in standard [BackgroundAudioSample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/BackgroundAudio-63bbc319) 
Uploaded in [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=604592796ECA14AA!462&authkey=!AIC4_FxfJr4Yq08&ithint=folder%2crtf)

Let me know if any one have come across this situations.

Thanks

Comment: Is In App Purchase working successfully when BackgroundAudioPlayer is not running?

Comment: Yes it works great in that case!